# Webstorm not ignoring directories marked "excluded"

Tags: extjs, webstorm

I have marked the WebContent/desktop/build directory as excluded, but Webstorm is still trying to index it. This is annoying whenever I build, and I have to wait for Webstorm to finish indexing before I can do anything.

How do I make it not index anything in the folder?

Here's what my Project Directories look like

[image: Workspace]

I've set the project to exclude the build directory

[image: Excluded Folders]

Yet Still...

[image: Indexing]

Comment: if you expand the excluded folders, are the subfolders also marked red and excluded?

Comment: Yes, everything is showing as excluded under this folder.

[screenshot](http://imgur.com/yGrYCi9)

If I try to mark individual files as plain text, I notice that they still have the "js" icon next to them rather than the plain text icon.

So, I can't mark the individual files as plain text to prevent indexing, and I can't mark the whole directory as excluded to prevent indexing...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders marked as JavaScript Libraries can't be excluded from indexing. And the WebContent directory is a library folder. Remove this folder from JavaScript libraries (Settings/Languages & Frameworks/JavaScript/Libraries, select your library and press Remove...). You can create a new library and add only those subfolders of WebContent directory you need being indexed to it

Comment: Thanks. This fixes. Should all my folders I want to have "intellisense" for be included in this, or just the ext folder?

Comment: I'd suggest including all folders you need getting completion from